# Does AVFrame store AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P data as YVU?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am decoding raw H.265 data using `avcodec_decode_video2` api. When I examine the resulting instance `pictYUV` of type `AVFrame,` I see that `pictYUV->format` is `AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P` and `pictYUV->data[0]` points to Y-plane. Both of these are expected. However, it appears `pictYUV->data[1]` seem to contain V-plane data and `pictYUV->data[2]`seem to contain U-plane data. My intuition was that `pictYUV->data` would store YUV planes in that order and not YVU planes.  Wondering if the data is always ordered as YVU or is there some flag I failed to look at. Regards.

Comment: What do you need here? You need to get non-planar format? or you just want to know why its planar?

Comment: Planar is fine. My observation was that data is being stored as Y, V, U in that order and not Y, U, V order,

Comment: From where did you detected that pictYUV->data[1] seems to contain V-Plane and not U-Plane? How did you validated it? Did you displayed the resulting buffer? How? I'm curious to know!

Answer (score 0):

`AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P` is planar YUV format (see P at the end of its name), so Y, U, and V are stored separated. There are also YUV formats with interleaved YUV format.
If you are getting the data from an IP camera, it is normal to get planar format.

Comment: The question is on the order of the planes. YUV vs YVU